# How to prevent 504 and get response to the client

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, timeout

I've got a node serverless hosted on AWS. I'm making a request from client side to insert an array of objects to a postgres db. This request payload has >10000 objects.

I've got this error
Access to fetch at 'endpoint/ModelSProductAttributesUploadExcelData' from origin domain has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Basically the server timesout before sending the request. What can i do to prevent this?

My logic for the insert is the following:

```
if (
    data[0].hasOwnProperty("SFC") &&
    data[0].hasOwnProperty("StyleDesc") &&
    data[0].hasOwnProperty("FabricDesc") &&
    data[0].hasOwnProperty("ColorDesc") &&
    data[0].hasOwnProperty("EventDesc") &&
    data[0].hasOwnProperty("DptDesc") &&
    data[0].hasOwnProperty("SubDptDesc") &&
    data[0].hasOwnProperty("ClassDesc") &&
    data[0].hasOwnProperty("InCollection") &&
    data[0].hasOwnProperty("Function")
  ) {
    const altered = data.reduce(
      (acc, item) =>
        (({ SFC, ...rest }) =>
          Object.entries(rest).reduce(
            (result, [Attribute, Value]) => [
              ...result,
              { SFC, Attribute, Value, Username: username },
            ],
            acc
          ))(item),
      []
    );
    let final_array = altered.filter(
      (item) =>
        item.Attribute !== "StyleDesc" &&
        item.Attribute !== "FabricDesc" &&
        item.Attribute !== "ColorDesc" &&
        item.Attribute !== "EventDesc" &&
        item.Attribute !== "DptDesc" &&
        item.Attribute !== "SubDptDesc" &&
        item.Attribute !== "SubDptDesc" &&
        item.Attribute !== "ClassDesc" &&
        item.Attribute !== "InCollection" &&
        item.Attribute !== "Function"
    );

    let sfcs = _.uniqBy(final_array, "SFC").map((item) => item.SFC);
    sfcs = sfcs.map((sfc) => `'${sfc}'`);
    console.log(sfcs);
    try {
      const client = connection();
      await client.connect();
      let query1 = `DELETE from models."InputAttributes" where "SFC" in (${sfcs})`;
      const result1 = await client.query(query1);
      console.log(result1);
      query2 = `INSERT into models."InputAttributes" ("SFC", "Attribute", "Value","Username","CreatedDate") VALUES`;
      for (let i = 0; i < final_array.length; i++) {
        if (i === final_array.length - 1) {
          string = `('${final_array[i].SFC}','${final_array[i].Attribute}','${final_array[i].Value}','${final_array[i].Username}',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)`;
        } else {
          string = `('${final_array[i].SFC}','${final_array[i].Attribute}','${final_array[i].Value}','${final_array[i].Username}',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),`;
        }
        query2 += string;
      }
      const result2 = await client.query(query2);
      if (result2) {
        res.sendStatus(200);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      res.sendStatus(500);
    }
  } else {
    res.sendStatus(400);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is not because of request timeout it is because you have not enabled the CORS policy in your server. hence the error: blocked by CORS policy.

```
//enable cors
var cors = require('cors')

var app = express()
app.use(cors())
```

regarding second part of your question to send a request without waiting just send the response without processing, if that works for your case.

```
//It would look something like this.
async (req, res)=>{
    res.send(responseData)
    // do the remaining processing here
}
```

Comment: I've enabled CORS policy, it's nothing to with that because i get a response for smaller request payloads. It's just if the array has more than let's say 10000 objects, then i get that error.

Comment: try with second option I posted, did that help?

Comment: can you post your code here. because in second case as I gave solution it should send the response without waiting for the processing. So you shouldn't get timeout error.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 if (
    data[0].hasOwnProperty("SFC") &&
    data[0].hasOwnProperty("StyleDesc") &&
    data[0].hasOwnProperty("FabricDesc") &&
    data[0].hasOwnProperty("ColorDesc") &&
    data[0].hasOwnProperty("EventDesc") &&
    data[0].hasOwnProperty("DptDesc") &&
    data[0].hasOwnProperty("SubDptDesc") &&
    data[0].hasOwnProperty("ClassDesc") &&
    data[0].hasOwnProperty("InCollection") &&
    data[0].hasOwnProperty("Function")
  ) {
    const altered = data.reduce(
      (acc, item) =>
        (({ SFC, ...rest }) =>
          Object.entries(rest).reduce(
            (result, [Attribute, Value]) => [
              ...result,
              { SFC, Attribute, Value, Username: username },
            ],
            acc
          ))(item),
      []
    );
    let final_array = altered.filter(
      (item) =>
        item.Attribute !== "StyleDesc" &&
        item.Attribute !== "FabricDesc" &&
        item.Attribute !== "ColorDesc" &&
        item.Attribute !== "EventDesc" &&
        item.Attribute !== "DptDesc" &&
        item.Attribute !== "SubDptDesc" &&
        item.Attribute !== "SubDptDesc" &&
        item.Attribute !== "ClassDesc" &&
        item.Attribute !== "InCollection" &&
        item.Attribute !== "Function"
    );

    let sfcs = _.uniqBy(final_array, "SFC").map((item) => item.SFC);
    sfcs = sfcs.map((sfc) => `'${sfc}'`);
    console.log(sfcs);
    try {
      const client = connection();
      await client.connect();
      let query1 = `DELETE from models."InputAttributes" where "SFC" in (${sfcs})`;
      const result1 = await client.query(query1);
      console.log(result1);
      let query2 = `INSERT into models."InputAttributes" ("SFC", "Attribute", "Value","Username","CreatedDate") VALUES`;
      for (let i = 0; i < final_array.length; i++) {
        if (i === final_array.length - 1) {
          string = `('${final_array[i].SFC}','${final_array[i].Attribute}','${final_array[i].Value}','${final_array[i].Username}',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)`;
        } else {
          string = `('${final_array[i].SFC}','${final_array[i].Attribute}','${final_array[i].Value}','${final_array[i].Username}',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),`;
        }
        query2 += string;
      }
      const result2 = await client.query(query2);
      // if (result2) {
      res.send(result2);
      // }
    } catch (error) {
      res.sendStatus(500);
    }
  } else {
    res.sendStatus(400);
  }
};
```